# How to realize NDSolve by Solve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I want realize the `NDSolve` by `Solve`,so I read some numerical integration resource. In common setting, ODEs can be solve by Euler forward integration，so I have define the function like this:

```
integrator[x_, y_, k_] := {x[[k + 1]] - x[[k]] == deltat*1,
    y[[k + 1]] - y[[k]] == 
    deltat*2 };
```

This function explain the discrete trajectories of ODES, if we define the initial condition like `x[[1]]=0,y[[1]]=0`, we can calculate the next point by `Solve` the pre-defined function  `integrator`.

```
x = {0, x1};
y = {0, y1};
deltat = 1*^-3;
Solve[integrator[x, y, 1], {x[[2]], y[[2]]}]
```

I can calculate the next point of $x,y$ is $(0.001,0.002)$ by `Shift+Enter`.

Now, I didn't know how to compute the next $k-1$ point,  should I define `x={0,x1,x2,x3,..,xk}; y={0,y1,y2,y3,..,yk}`, and then calculate points step by step and substitute in step by step? It seems not smart.

Any advice will be very appreciate!

Thank you!

Update:

@Daniel Thank you, but I think the answer is not suit for the general form, for example when x[k+1]-x[k]=x[k+1]*y[k+1]+1, the integrators is implicit, so must use Slove to find root of constrain equations!

Comment: Look at e.g. "Table"

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you, I have try the `Table` and `For`, Use `Table` to assign a series of variables to x, It's redundant, maybe I could define `x` as a function of time?

Comment: @Ben Why not to use `NSolve` for numerical computation or `FindRoot` which is more powerful and can be used to solve system of nonlinear ODEs or PDEs?

Answer (score 3):

Make it simpler by returning the new x,y from "integrate" like:

```
integrator[x_, y_, k_] := {x + deltat*1, y + deltat*2};

x = 0;
y = 0;
deltat = 1*^-3;
Table[
 {x, y} = integrator[x, y, 1]
 , {5}]
```

[image]

Comment: You code are amazing! the code avoid use `Solve`, if `integrator` have more complex and general form, eg. the integrator is implicit, `integrator[x_, y_, k_] := {x[[k + 1]] - x[[k]] == deltat*(x[[k+1]]*x[[k]]+y[[k+1]]+1),
    y[[k + 1]] - y[[k]] == 
    deltat*x[[k+1]]+2 };`, Can i define `Function` in this simple way?

Comment: I defined the function like this is that the format may be implicit, so I maybe need to use the `solve` function, and define the $x, y$ as a list, `[[k]]` representing the value of each time step, your answer gave me some inspiration, thanks again!

Comment: If you can solve the equations for the new x,y, you may use this in the integration function to make it simpler..

Comment: you are right, ‘NDSolve’ and ‘Integrate’ is very powerful, the reason I did this is try to repeat the numerical integration, and understand how implicit Euler method work, after study i can program a similar ‘NDSove’, the study is the process of trying.

Comment: If the integrator is implicit, we can’t define function in this simple way.

Comment: Implicit implies we should find the root by solve the complex constraint equation.

Comment: That is right. implicit is always more complicated, but often more stable.

Comment: Just curious: what is the point of k in the definition of integrator?

Comment: In my simplified version it is not use any more.

Comment: @chris, `k` means the time step(in this example, it means we have recursive calculate function `integrator` k times, the program can output `x[[k]]`)