# The use of `NestList `

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming, iteration

After read Michael [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258396/how-to-realize-ndsolve-by-nsolve-with-the-implicit-constraint-equations/258409#258409), code use `NestList` to compute and feed in numerical integration. I want to learn this idea into my code.

In the `NestList` document, this function have three parameter, eg. `f, expr, n`.if define `f`, `NestList` seems to map expr to `f[expr]`,'f[f[expr]]',... n times.

So I refer Michael [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258396/how-to-realize-ndsolve-by-nsolve-with-the-implicit-constraint-equations/258409#258409),

```
deltat = 1*^-3;
integrator[x_, y_, {x0_, y0_}] := {x[1], y[1]} /. 
   FindRoot[{x[1] - x[0] == deltat,
      y[1] - y[0] == deltat}, {{x[0], x0}, {y[0], y0}}];
integrator[x, y, {0, 0}]
```

And

```
NestList[integrator[x, y, {y[0], y[0]}], {x[0], y[0]}(* condition *), 4]
```

I want calculate 4 times nesting, at beginning, $x0,y0$ is the initial value, and call `integrator` to get $x1,y1$, and repeat, $x1,y1$ as initial point, call `integrator` again, and find root again. Above code's output is not what I expected.

I still don't understand `NestList` enough, I seem to only know this form, but don’t know how to use it for specific problems.

**Update**(I still have a bugs with my code, sad, Others gave the right answer, but I still failed)

```
ClearAll[integrator, myintegrator, stepintegrator];
deltat = 1*^-3;
integrator[x_, y_, {x0_, y0_}] := {x[1], y[1]} /. 
   FindRoot[{x[1] - x[0] == deltat,
      y[1] - y[0] == deltat}, {{x[0], x0}, {y[0], y0}}];
(*integrator[x,y,{0,0}]*)

myintegrator[x_, y_][x0_, 
  y0_] := {Sequence @@ integrator[x, y, {x0, y0}]}
stepintegrator = myintegrator[x, y];
NestList[stepintegrator, {0, 0}, 2]
```

Comment: Let's say: `f[{x_, y_}] := {x + 1, y + 1};` is a function that takes a list and returns a list. Execute: `NestList[f, {x, y}, 4]` to see the result.

Comment: read the answer code a bit more closely—you'll notice Michael uses a *function* as the first argument to nestlist, by expecting `myIntegrator[param1, param2,..][{x0, y0}]` to return a point in the trajectory. (note that this is of the form `f[a][b]`—`f[a]` is a function!) He then takes `stepIntegrator = myIntegrator[param1, param2,..]`, which is, as mentioned, a function. `NestList` always takes a function as its first argument; see [the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html). You should use `integrator[x_, y_][{x0_, y0_}]` and `integrator[x,y]` in `NestList` instead.

Comment: @thorimur Thank you, it is my first time to know function as ‘function[para,para][x,y]’, you are right, I should read more carefully, it is details can’t be ignored!

Comment: @Syed I have try this code, it doesn’t work when I need update condition, the problem maybe due to ‘f’ should have second parameters like ‘f[para,para][x,y]’ in my example.

Comment: It is a simple example to show how `NestList` works. `NestList` can keep applying the function at the last result.

Comment: @Syed, I have read more closely, so I write the same form `f[a][b]`, `b` represent the point we need compute, but the output become `{{0, 0}, myintegrator[x, y][{0, 0}], 
 myintegrator[x, y][myintegrator[x, y][{0, 0}]]}` if I just want calculate 2 times. I'am sorry I didn't master the keypoint of Michael code.

Comment: @Syed, I have do it, Thank you! Code I have update in the origin question(so I close this question): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258396/how-to-realize-ndsolve-by-nsolve-with-the-implicit-constraint-equations/258404#258404

Comment: Best of luck to you @Ben.